What is the header/certificate format used in /etc/ssl/cert.pem?
When exporting the certificate from a server I'm using via
openssl s_client -servername my_server -connect my_server:443 | openssl x509 -text

I get a header with lots of data about the certificate, as well as the certificate itself. This is, however, not directly appendable to /etc/ssl/cert.pem - that file is divided in blocks, which start with a ### with the org name, a === with one line with country, org unit and org name, then the human readable header I got from openssl x509 and, finally, the cert itself.
Example:
# $OpenBSD: cert.pem,v 1.22.2.1 2021/09/30 18:28:20 deraadt Exp $
### /C=ES/CN=Autoridad de Certificacion Firmaprofesional CIF A62634068

=== /C=ES/CN=Autoridad de Certificacion Firmaprofesional CIF A62634068
Certificate:
    Data:
        ...
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Validity


Is there an easy way to export the cert directly in a way it can just be concatenated to /etc/ssl/cert.pem?

The format of this file is defined in RFC 7468 which says the following at the start of section 2:

Textual encoding begins with a line comprising "-----BEGIN ", a label, and "-----", and ends with a line comprising "-----END ", a label, and "-----".  Between these lines, or "encapsulation boundaries", are base64-encoded data according to Section 4 of [RFC4648].  (PEM [RFC1421] referred to this data as the "encapsulated text portion".)  Data before the encapsulation boundaries are permitted, and parsers MUST NOT malfunction when processing such data.  Furthermore, parsers SHOULD ignore whitespace and other non-base64 characters and MUST handle different newline conventions.

And adds the following as section 5.2:

5.2.  Explanatory Text
Many tools are known to emit explanatory text before the BEGIN and after the END lines for PKIX certificates, more than any other type. If emitted, such text SHOULD be related to the certificate, such as providing a textual representation of key data elements in the certificate.
Subject: CN=Atlantis
Issuer: CN=Atlantis
Validity: from 7/9/2012 3:10:38 AM UTC to 7/9/2013 3:10:37 AM UTC   
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIBmTCCAUegAwIBAgIBKjAJBgUrDgMCHQUAMBMxETAPBgNVBAMTCEF0bGFudGlz    
MB4XDTEyMDcwOTAzMTAzOFoXDTEzMDcwOTAzMTAzN1owEzERMA8GA1UEAxMIQXRs  
YW50aXMwXDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAANLADBIAkEAu+BXo+miabDIHHx+yquqzqNh     
Ryn/XtkJIIHVcYtHvIX+S1x5ErgMoHehycpoxbErZmVR4GCq1S2diNmRFZCRtQID         
AQABo4GJMIGGMAwGA1UdEwEB/wQCMAAwIAYDVR0EAQH/BBYwFDAOMAwGCisGAQQB     
gjcCARUDAgeAMB0GA1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMCBggrBgEFBQcDAzA1BgNVHQEE      
LjAsgBA0jOnSSuIHYmnVryHAdywMoRUwEzERMA8GA1UEAxMIQXRsYW50aXOCASow     
CQYFKw4DAh0FAANBAKi6HRBaNEL5R0n56nvfclQNaXiDT174uf+lojzA4lhVInc0     
ILwpnZ1izL4MlI9eCSHhVQBHEp2uQdXJB+d5Byg=    
-----END CERTIFICATE-----



When you pipe the output, you already get rid of stderr (at least for the info being piped). Removing -text also removes the info that's in the /etc/ssl/cert.pem file in the headers (things like key serial, usage, alt names, etc)

The question was whether there is a way to export the certificate in the same format that's used in the /etc/ssl/cert.pem file, with the header and the cert data rather than just the bare cert in x509 format.

That IS the question, @garethTheRed - the .pem in question is a concatenation of  x509's prefixed with small headers. Does that header+x509 format have a name or is the header merely informative, and completely optional?

Can you turn that (the RFC mention) into the answer?
